# pip install PyQt6 fails: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

Tags: python, linux, pip, pyqt6

Installing PyQt6 on a Linux Mint box fails with this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
```

The same error is mentioned in several posts, sometimes for PyQt6,  sometimes for other modules.  However,  none of the proposed solutions (like upgrading pip) seems to work.

Any suggestions on how to figure out what is wrong?

Below are the commands I used.  Installation is in a virtual environment (but installing it on the main machine results in the same error).

```
johan@morla:~/work\> cat /etc/issue
Linux Mint 19 Tara \n \l

johan@morla:~/work\> python --version
Python 3.9.12
johan@morla:~/work\> python -m venv env
johan@morla:~/work\> . env/bin/activate
johan@morla:~/work\> pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        22.1
setuptools 58.1.0
johan@morla:~/work\> pip install PyQt6
Collecting PyQt6
  Using cached PyQt6-6.3.0-cp37-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (7.8 MB)
Collecting PyQt6-sip<14,>=13.2
  Using cached PyQt6_sip-13.3.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (306 kB)
Collecting PyQt6
  Using cached PyQt6-6.2.3-cp36-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (7.7 MB)
  Using cached PyQt6-6.2.2-cp36-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (7.7 MB)
  Using cached PyQt6-6.2.1-cp36-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (7.7 MB)
  Using cached PyQt6-6.2.0.tar.gz (1.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [33 lines of output]
      Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
      /usr/bin/qmake -query
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/johan/work/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
```

Comment: Using --no-cache-dir gives exactly the same error

Comment: Are you on 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: I am on x86_64,   5.4.0-42-generic #46~18.04.1-Ubuntu

Comment: execute: `python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools` `python -m pip install pyqt6 --no-cache-dir`

Comment: setuptools were upgraded from 58.1.0 to 62.3.1 .  Still the same error.

Comment: What do you get if you run: `python -m pip install pyqt6-qt6`

Comment: I see, according to the [manylinux README](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux), the pyqt6-qt6 dependency has the format manylinux_x_y (
PyQt6_Qt6-6.3.0-py3-none-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl) which is compatible for ubuntu >= 21.04 but your linux mint is based on lower ubuntu so try to compile, can you update your linux? Anyway I will try to find a solution for your current version of OS but it may take time. The x_y indicates the version of glibc the library was compiled with and your OS has a probably lower glibc version.

Comment: Your version of linux is old, for at least 3 years.

Comment: You are right: I have glibc 2.27. Yes I know I should upgrade, just afraid that it will break something with little time to handle issues :-)  I thought manylinux1 is compatible with CentOS 5.11, which probably has an glibc as well;  so I am wrong?

Comment: The problem is not PyQt6 but its dependency which is [pyqt6-qt6](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt6-Qt6/) whose wheel has the format manylinux_x_y

Answer (score 0):

Based on @eyllanesc's input:  the problem is that PyQt6 depends on pyqt6-qt6, and the currently available wheels for pyqt6-qt6 require glibc version 2.28 or greater.  As I am using Linux Mint 19 which has glibc 2.27, pip tries to build from source,  which fails.

Hint: to check the glibc version, try  `ldd --version`

Solution: upgrade Mint, or wait until @eyllanesc has a solution with an older glibc (or try to compile it myself).

Is there a way to get pip to give a clearer error message?